# In which situation should I choose Silverlight or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, web-applications

Microsoft offers two tools and I guess they are thought to solve specific problem. So my question is: what are the key-points that will make me choose one or another technology?

As a subquestion, when you have good knowledge in C# and desktop application but no experience in web application, what is the learning curve of ASP.Net MVC

Comment: Will your application be used by the general public, or only by a controlled set of users (within a coroporate environment, for example) who you know will have (or can have) the Silverlight plugin installed?

Comment: The application will be accessible only from the intranet and exclusively with IE9+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both great platforms and I use both, including WPF.  Silverlight, however, may not be receiving a great deal of community/Microsoft support in the future.  So you need to factor this in to your decision making process.  MVC, on the other hand, has a great deal of support from both the dev community and Microsoft.  Plus, it's been my experience that it's easier to find MVC talent than Silverlight.

Since you have no or little web experience, the learning curve may be a little tough for MVC.  If your desktop experience is winforms, then transtioning to Silverlight will also be tough due to the XAML learning curve.  Also, the Silverlight route may aid in the transition to Metro XAML/C# stack, if that's important to you.

If I was in your shoes and I had to make a decision between the two, I'd opt for MVC.

Comment: By the way, my desktop experience includes XAML. But if MVC learning curve is as tough as XAML maybe I'd choose Silverlight as the business is really, really (really) time oriented.

Comment: The transition to MVC can pose a bit of a challenge for experienced ASP.NET devs.  If you know XAML/C# and time is an issue, then Silverlight by all means.  The user experience is great in Silverlight and it's a great tool to work with.  I'd also recommend that you consider the MVVM pattern in your design.

Answer (score 3):

If you expect your applications to work on any platform, choose MVC. Silverlight is only going to work on platforms that support it. So that means no mobile. I don't know about you, but that would worry me.

Comment: It doesn't matter in my specific case, it'll run in an intranet and the only specification is Internet Explorer 9+

Comment: So you'd rather pigeonhole your development for future expansion?

Comment: basically he means "don't put all your eggs in one basket". Theres no need to make decisions that limit all possibilities because it won't hinder you NOW. in a years time you might find that you needed mobile and then you'll wish you'd have gone for the solution which would have never hindered you in the first place.

Comment: Silverlight is not very flexible platform wise, whereas MVC you can take advantage of HTML5. It will allow for future development, if lets say 6 months down the road the expectation is for your application to run on something other than IE9+, like iOS.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Is Silverlight obsolete? When I read you all, it's like MVC does what Silverlight does but on all environments.

Comment: Key difference: Silverlight requires a browser plug-in, MVC does not (MVC is the name of the server-side pattern that is used), the client-side is just a website.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MVC, the learning resources are excellent. I would start with the [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials). These will help you understand Microsoft's implementation of MVC, although are less useful when it comes to website development (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) itself.

However, since your application will only be used in-house on IE9, and you have XAML experience then I'd go for Silverlight.

Comment: This brings up a really important point - unless your application requires a trivial user interface there will be a potentially significant learning curve with respect to the UI. Building a great-looking, rich user interface will be harder in a web app than with Silverlight if you're coming at the problem with XAML experience but no web experience.